# Why is my tkinter scrollbar is not showing up on my text widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a restaurant menu with a text widget to display my menu items. I want a vertical scrollbar on it's far right but it isn't showing up with my current code. How do I go about fixing this?

```
# Text Widget For Menu Items
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar( orient='vertical',command = tk.YView,bg = 'white')
scrollbar.grid(column = 0,row = 2,)
items = tk.Text(bg = 'black',font = ('Baskerville', 18),wrap = tk.WORD,yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set,height = 20)
items.grid(column = 0,row = 2, columnspan = 4,padx = 20,pady = 20)
scrollbar.config( command = items.yview )

# Title And Buttons
head = tk.Label(text = "Menu",font = ("Garamond",40),bg = 'black')
head.grid(column = 0,row = 0,columnspan = 4, sticky = 'N', pady = 10)

app = tk.Button(text="Entrees",width = 12,height = 2,command = lambda: printItems("Entree"))
main = tk.Button(text="Mains",width = 12,height = 2,command = lambda: printItems("Main"))
des = tk.Button(text="Desserts",width = 12,height = 2,command = lambda: printItems("Dessert"))
deal = tk.Button(text="Configure",width = 12,height = 2,command = lambda: editWindow())
```

[image]

Comment: If you want the scrollbar at the far right, why did you put it in column 0?  It would have to be in column 4 (or higher) to not be overlapped by the Text.

Comment: Why not use `ScrolledText` instead of `Text` widget?

Answer (score 1):

You've put both the scrollbar and text widget in column 0. If you want the scrollbar on the right, put it in column 5 since the text widget spans 4 columns.  You'll also want to use the `sticky` attribute when adding the scrollbar so it fills the space allocated to it.

```
scrollbar.grid(column = 5,row = 2, sticky="ns")
```

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, you have put the `Scrollbar` in column 0 which is overlapped/covered by the `Text` widget.

I would suggest to put both the `Text` and `Scrollbar` widgets in a frame because it is more easier to arrange them independent of the other buttons and label:

```py
# create a frame that occupies 4 columns to align with the buttons
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg="black")
frame.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=4, padx=20, pady=20)

# scrollbar put in right side of the frame and fill vertically
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical', command=tk.YView, bg='white')
scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill='y')

# Text widget put in the left side of the frame
items = tk.Text(frame, bg='black', font=('Baskerville', 18), wrap=tk.WORD,
                yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set, height=20)
items.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

scrollbar.config(command=items.yview)
```

And the output:

[image]