# How to make my tkinter scrollbar fit into the text widget properly using grid?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am building a restaurant menu in python with tkinter. I have a text widget to display the menu items and a scrollbar to go in it. However, the scrollbar is outside the widget and not the same height (see image). I also want the scrollbar to be a white bar juxtaposed with the black background of the text widget. How do I go about it?

Relevant code:

```
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(w)
scrollbar.grid(column = 4,row = 2,sticky='NS')

# Text Widget For Menu Items
items = tk.Text(bg = 'black',font = ('Baskerville', 18),wrap = tk.WORD,height = 20,yscrollcommand= scrollbar.set)
items.grid(column = 0,row = 2, columnspan = 4,padx = 15,pady = 10)
items.tag_config("lmargin", lmargin1=8, lmargin2=8)
scrollbar.config(command = items.yview)
```

[image]

Comment: See my answer to your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76654344/why-is-my-tkinter-scrollbar-is-not-showing-up-on-my-text-widget).

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is create a `tk.Frame` and pack both the Text widget in and the Scrollbar widget in to `side='right'`.  Then you can use `grid` on the Frame to fit in into your main window, and have it columnspan 4 columns instead of your Text widget.  That is typically what I do when working with scrollbars because they can be tricky to use with a grid manager.

It may look something like this:

```
frame = tk.Frame(w)
scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(frame, orient='vertical')

# Text Widget For Menu Items
items = tk.Text(frame, bg = 'black',font = ('Baskerville', 18),wrap = tk.WORD,height = 20,yscrollcommand= scrollbar.set)
items.tag_config("lmargin", lmargin1=8, lmargin2=8)
scrollbar.config(command = items.yview)

items.pack()
scrollbar.pack(side='right', fill='y')
frame.grid(column=0, row=2, columnspan=4)
```

As for changing the color of the scrollbar, a ttk scrollbar may assist you better.  I found this:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/changing-the-appearance-of-a-scrollbar-in-tkinter-using-ttk-styles